# How to configure Nginx for Ember.js + Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, ember.js

The scenario is that I'd like to use Wordpress as a backend API provider for our Ember.js frontend app.

The Ember.js frontend needs to be served from the root, and the Wordpress instance ideally would be reachable by going to a subdirectory. So for example on localhost it would be `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/wordpress`

On the disk the two are deployed in `/srv/http/ember` and `/srv/http/wordpress` respectively.

I was trying to assemble the configuration going by the example on the Nginx site:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

The config:

```
http {

    upstream php {
      server   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /srv/http/ember;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;

        location /wordpress {
            root /srv/http/wordpress;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;
        }

    }

}
```

However this is obviously not the correct solution.
Upon trying to access the address `http://localhost/wordpress/index.php` I get the following in the logs:

```
2016/05/01 17:50:14 [error] 4332#4332: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /wordpress/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

The recipe isn't clear about where to put the `root` directive for the location of wordpress. I also tried with adding `index index.php`, which doesn't help either.

(Serving the Ember app works fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it seems that the `location ~ \.php$` block is used by WordPress alone. However, it needs a root of `/srv/http` in order to find the script files for URIs beginning with `/wordpress` under the local path `/srv/http/wordpress`.

As there are two locations which both use the same WordPress root, it is possibly cleaner to make `/srv/http` the default (that is, inherited from the `server` block) and move `root /srv/http/ember;` into a separate `location /` block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /srv/http;

    location / {
        root /srv/http/ember;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
    }

    location /wordpress {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }
}
```

Notice that the default URI in `location /wordpress` is `/wordpress/index.php` and not `/index.php` as you originally had.

I have explicitly set `SCRIPT_FILENAME` as it may or may not appear in your `fastcgi.conf` file.

`fastcgi_split_path_info` has been removed as it is unnecessary in your specific case, and I think it would actually break WordPress the way you had it.